# Android Studio does not show the res directory

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

I have an Android project checked out in Android Studio (4.0.1). The build.gradle contains the following sourceSets block (snippet shown below). It is meant to prevent certain values resource files from being included in the packaged aar (I only want to include values-en-rUS and values-es-rUS in the aar).

The aar gets packaged correctly and contains only values-en-rUS and values-es-rUS, as expected.

```
sourceSets {

        main {
            def resSrc = fileTree(dir: 'src/main/res').matching { exclude { details ->
                (!details.file.canonicalPath.matches('.*values-(en|es)-rUS.*')
                        && details.file.canonicalPath.matches('.*values-.*'))
            } }
            
            ...
            res.srcDirs = [ resSrc ]
            ...

        }
    }
```

However, Android Studio does not show me the `res` directory (the entire directory!) anymore in the "Project" sidebar when "Android" is selected, and the Java code files can no longer resolve the ids or layouts (e.g. `findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet_layout)` -- they show as red squiggly lines).

How can I make it so that Android Studio continues to show the res directory in this case?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sourceSets {

    main {
        def resSrc = fileTree(dir: 'src/main/res').matching { exclude { details ->
            (!details.file.canonicalPath.matches('.*values-(en|es)-rUS.*')
                    && details.file.canonicalPath.matches('.*values-.*'))
        } }

        res.srcDirs = [resSrc, 'src/main/res']

    }
}
```

**Note:** If two or more resource directories contain the same resource file, an error occurs during resource merging.

[image]

For more information: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/add-resources

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what I expect. I want to set res.srcDirs such that it excludes some files from my 'src/main/res', rather than merge two resource dirs. I couldn't find how to perform a split rather than a merge